# Running Tests with Selenium Python on Website but cannnot click links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm try to run some test on my server's capabilities to have multiple visitors and make sure I can handle the traffic so I have opted to use selenium and python because I am most familiar with them

this is what I have so far (work in progress):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.on-demandlogistics.com/home.html")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "test"))
)
element.click()
```

I have tried CSS Selector, Xpath, and even creating special class in the HTML code but I cannot get selenium to follow the link that a I want

I want to follow Log-in then I will continue from there

the HTML is as follow but feel free to follow the link (http://www.on-demandlogistics.com/home.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>On-Demand Logistics | Home</title>
  </head>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav main-nav">
      <div class="nav-grid-container">
          <div class="nav-grid-item link-img">
            <a href="mailto:slefebvre@on-demandlogistics.com">
              <img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item">
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item">
            <a href="services.html">Services</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item">
            <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item">
            <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item test">
            <a href="login.html">Log-In</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-grid-item right-imgs">
              <img src="images/footerlogo.png" alt="">
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      </header>
    <section class="main-section">
      <h1>Welcome to On-Demand Logistics!</h1>
      <div class="grid-container-even">
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
          <h2>
            We are a 3PL (third party logistics) and consulting company
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">
          <img src="images/openmap.jpg" width=400px hieght=1000px alt="This is the open globe image">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">
...
```

any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are selecting is a `div`. You want to click on the anchor tag inside it-

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".test > a"))
)
element.click()
```

The css selector `.test > a` simply means choose the `a` tag that is a child of the element with class name `test`.

Sometimes, selenium has trouble registering clicks on nested elements. Which seems to be the case here. In this case, you can either initiate the `click` from javascript like so-

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

Or you can simply get the `href` from the `a` tag and do a `.get` manually-

```py
driver.get(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the code finishes running and exits with code 0 but it doesn't actually click the link and I cannot figure out why

Comment: Thanks! your second option worked as expected (I didn't try the first one)